# Is it possible to set-up shorter route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Now I have routing set up like this.

```
resources :communities do
    resources :community_topics
end
```

But I want routing like this

> communities/32435/topics/745

Yes, I'd like to use 'topics' instead of community_topics

Can anyone show me how I can archive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
resources :communities do
  resources :community_topics, :path => 'topics'
end
```

The doc for resources is [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources)